# What are Naiji special abilities in Super Meat Boy?

Tags: super-meat-boy

I've just unlocked Naiji (from Acquaria) in Super Meat Boy (PC version, but I believe the platform doesn't matter). What are her special abilities, and how to use them?

I've already found that while pressing `Shift` (the run button), she descends very slowly in air. I've also found that she can jump lightning fast, but I still don't understand how to trigger this ability, nor how to control it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike other characters, holding the Shift button (or the Y button for those with a gamepad) does not maker her run faster. In her case, it activates her special -- the color change and slowing of descent you already realized.

What it sounds like you haven't realized, is that when you let go of Shift, you'll perform an air dash, but become locked out of performing another slowfall / airdash until you touch another surface.

Something like this is rather hard to explain with words alone, so I direct you to this [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BtA5Zv8XTKs) demonstration to clarify.

Comment: That's really hard to master...

Comment: Ah, but the benefits are worth it.

Comment: Like there is anything in meatboy that is not hard to master =)

Comment: Dying isn't too hard.